# how to tweet an image,url,text at a time using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

How to tweet an image, url, text at a time on Twitter means as a single tweet in an load event using C#. Is their any chances to over this kind off issues ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String sans = "";
        String tosh = "";
        var oauth_consumer_key = "8888888888888888888888888888";
        var oauth_consumer_secret = "11111111111111111111111111111";

        if (Request["oauth_token"] == null)
        {
            OAuthTokenResponse reqToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

            Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={0}",
                reqToken.Token));
        }
        else
        {
            string requestToken = Request["oauth_token"].ToString();
            string pin = Request["oauth_verifier"].ToString();
            var tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_consumer_secret,
                requestToken,
                pin);
            OAuthTokens accesstoken = new OAuthTokens()
            {
                AccessToken = tokens.Token,
                AccessTokenSecret = tokens.TokenSecret,
                ConsumerKey = oauth_consumer_key,
                ConsumerSecret = oauth_consumer_secret
            };

            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(accesstoken,tosh, new StatusUpdateOptions() { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });

            if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            {
                Response.Write("we did it!");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("it's all bad.");
            }

        }           

 }
```

Comment: So what is the error here ?

Comment: their is no error but i need to display an image from asp.net page into twitter as a tweet @HarveySpecter

Comment: What is the question ? What problem are you having ?